# Show that this graph must have a region whose degree is at least 4!!!

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

If I draw a 3-regular simple, connected, planar graph of more than 4 vertices, how do I prove that the graph must have a region whose degree is at least 4?

I came to the following proof but unsure if it's correct

> Let's assume, for the sake of contradiction, that every region in the graph has a degree less than 4. This means that every region is surrounded by at most 3 edges
> Since the graph is 3-regular, this implies that every vertex on the boundary of a region is connected to at most 2 vertices within that region. This means that the vertices on the boundary are not connected to at least one other vertex within the region.

> However, this assumption contradicts the fact that the graph is connected. If no vertex on the boundary of a region is connected to more than 2 vertices within that region, then the region is effectively disconnected from the rest of the graph. This means that there would be isolated vertices or disjoint subgraphs within the graph, violating the connectedness property.

> Since the assumption of every region having a degree less than 4 leads to a contradiction with the connectedness of the graph, we must conclude that there must exist at least one region in the graph with a degree of at least 4. This ensures that the graph remains connected and satisfies the properties of a 3-regular simple, connected, planar graph.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "This means that the vertices on the boundary are **not** connected to at least one other vertex within the region." and  "If no vertex on the boundary of a region is connected to more than 2 vertices within that region, then the **region is effectively disconnected from the rest of the graph**.", especially the parts in bold?